# MobileFirst cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mobile, plugins, installation, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded [*mobileFirst 7.1.ZIP* from here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/).

When I tried to install the software in eclipse, I catch this exception:

> cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found

My current softWare configuration is:
**Windows 7 64bits Eclipse Luna SR2 **

Comment: From the given link which 7.1 zip are you installing ? you should install studio plugin 7.1 zip.I use Eclipse Juno and did not face any error